# Process Id is changed while running the process

Tags: c#, process

I am using `System.Diagnostics` in c#. My problem is I am using code for starting and killing the process in c# and it's working fine. But my question is my process id is changing in-between while running the process. Is that possible. If yes then how can I get the actual process id which I want to kill. I can't do it by name because I have multiple instance are running on different at a time and I want to kill only single instance on started port.

My code is :

```
Process p2 = new Process();
                    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo2 =
                        new ProcessStartInfo(
                            unitoolLauncherExePath,
                            "options --port " + port);

  p2.StartInfo = processStartInfo2;
  p2.Start();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  int processId = p2.Id;
```

Now it will return something like 14823 and when I am trying to kill it it's changed.

```
Process[] _proceses = null;
            _proceses = Process.GetProcessesByName("UNIToolAPIServer");
            foreach (Process proces in _proceses)
            {
                if (proces.Id == processId)
                {                    
                    proces.Kill();                        
                }
                    
            }
```

But here nothing is killed because no process with the above id is fetched.

Comment: why not simply remember/store the process instance when you created the process and reuse it later?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Eh, why doesn't the process, you start, automatically exit when done? Then you would have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the process id of a running process does not change while it is running.

If there is no process to kill with the process id of the process you started, it means either of two things:

- The process has already exited before you obtain the process list.
- The name of the process is not "*UNIToolAPIServer*".

Comment: Or the program started a copy of itself and terminated which means there is still a matching process running, but it isn't the one OP's program started directly. Some programs does that, for instance to sandbox itself, or to upgrade itself, etc.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, that's covered by the first possibility i mentioned "_The process has already exited before you obtain the process list._". Whether the original process spawns another process, or whether it is just another (unrelated) process with the same name that is already running for whatever reasons (for example a "left-over" from prior experimentations), is unanswerable. There are so many possibilities of why there might be "other" UNIToolAPIServer processes active on the asker's machine...

Comment: @StickToTheProcess, It's already running without exist but the process id is different. And process name is correct FYI.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar, "_process id is different_" then this is not the process your code started. Simple as that. Since the process you are interested in is not the process started by your program, as a first step figure out when and what starts that process you are interested in.

Comment: @StickToTheProcess, You are correct actually I am starting service using Launcher file so it's process id was different. I tried manually and I found that. If I am using exe then it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill the created process you should keep the process-object and call the kill method on it. There should be no need to go thru all the processes in the system to find the started process. For example:

```
public class MyProcess{
  private Process myProcess;
  ...
  public void Start(){
    myProcess = new Process();
    var processStartInfo2 = new ProcessStartInfo(
                            unitoolLauncherExePath,
                            "options --port " + port);

    myProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo2;
    myProcess.Start();
  }
  public void Kill(){
    if(myProcess != null && !myProcess.HasExited){
          myProcess.Kill();
     }
  }
}
```